# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip removes image padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sequence of `img` tags with Bootstrap 3 tooltips appearing over them on hover. When you hover over them, the tooltip appears but the image padding is removed and strings them all together; see first and second screenshot:

[image: Original Padding]

[image: Broken Padding]

Here is my code:

```
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/pommmes/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="pommmes" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/kittycaitie/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="kittycaitie" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/1stBoss11111/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="1stBoss11111" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/iGalaxHD/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="iGalaxHD" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/liamflaherty63/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="liamflaherty63" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/Fields/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="Fields" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/MarkoGameZ/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="MarkoGameZ" />
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({
            trigger: 'hover'
        }) 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: James, Can you show a live example?

Comment: This is CSS issue, can you post styles?

Comment: specifically img styles which are not of a specific class

Comment: Live example: http://eastsussexcoach.com/james/

Comment: Whit Firefox your sample work fine

Comment: @scaisEdge True. Just tried Safari in addition to Chrome which was what I was originally using, and the error appears there too. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I'm  using Firefox 38.05 and work fine, non padding lost. Probably somethings  related with webkit. Check on this [bootstrap browser bugs](http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is webkit rendering issue. Original markup you are using contains inline elements and looks roughly like this:

```
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/pommmes/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="pommmes" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/kittycaitie/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="kittycaitie" />
<img src="//minotar.net/helm/1stBoss11111/32" data-toggle="tooltip" tabindex="50" data-placement="top" title="1stBoss11111" />
```

Since `img` are inline elements by default browser respects whitespaces between them, including newlines. Those whitespaces are rendered as initial margin between images. This is what you consider "normal".

What happens when you hover over image is that the image gets wrapped into `div` container, this is how Bootstrap displays toolstips, since it can't append tooltip element into `img` it creates wrapper container to put tooltip there temporarily.

However `div` inserted between two inline elements breaks previous whitespace rendering and for some reason it's not reverted back when wrapper is removed.

The simplest fix is to init tooltips like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
    })
});
```

which dictates Bootsrap to append tooltips to `body` container instead of hovered element.

In the demo below, try to comment out `container: 'body'` and see how buggy behavior is back.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/4bTvaKzP1qY1CRs3q0OK?p=preview